# Voltage used up by a transistor and shift registers

Tags: transistors, resistors, resistance, shift-register

i am on a project 8x8x8 LED cube and I am stuck on the value of register i should use.

Talking about single layer
I am using 2N5296 transistor for common cathode and 8 shift registers for controlling 64 anodes.The LED I have used are from robocaze.com which are 3mm Blue LED undiffused.

Now the problem arises between shift register and anodes of LED I need to connect resistor and I want to calculate its value.But I dont know that what amount of voltage and current are used up by the transistor and the shift register (74HC595).

Also i would like to give 20mA to the LEDs.

If someone can help me figuring it out then I will be very thankful to him.

Datasheet Links :-

[Transistor 2N5296](http://www.svntc.com/TPDF/199.pdf)

[Shift Register 74HC595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc595.pdf)

Thanks in advance

-YASH LOTAN

Comment: Did you try to read the datsheets? The voltage drop of a 595 is specified (for a few currents).

Comment: What LEDs are you using? And how much current do you want to push through your LEDs?

Answer (score 1):

use 2n2222 transistor.i had made this 8x8x8 led cube[image]

see the transistor at left end.use 2 transistor to control one cathode array.if you need more help i can give you full details.

Comment: Whats the value of R3,R4,.....R18? I also tried it but people on forums suggested me using single transistor. BTW this schematic i saw on instructables.

Comment: use 1k resistor,its resistor to protect transistor,you can use 2.2k too